Can't type anything at installation
Absolutely newbie here. Just downloaded and I cant proceed with the installation the system asks me info to create an account but nothing happens, I cant type anything. The cursor keeps blinking. Also I noticed the caps lock is on and I can't disable it, seems to be stuck. I can t find any answer to this problem. Some people asked the same but on another stage, they already have an account . I'm stuck in the beginning.

Does your keyboard work otherwise?

No. I can use only the pad to navigate but the keyboard is frozen.

Is it a laptop or desktop? And (if desktop), is the keyboard connected directly via USB or Bluetooth? Can you try a different keyboard?

I meant, with ubuntu I can't use it. With win10 it's ok.

It is a laptop.

Some keys of the first row seem to be working because I can adjust the brightness of the screen.

And now it displayed a black screen: initranfs. I cant enter password because the keyboard keeps stuck. But minutes ago it displayed another screen : grub. And I was able to type there but the instructions ls (hd0, 1) didnt work. So I tried rebooting and here I am on initramfs.

Ah. That's the way  you work here, closing the question without an answer. Poor site.

I’m not sure the exact reason for closure - but you might want to provide a bit more information. We don’t even know what Ubuntu version you’re trying to install, or what hardware you’re trying to install it on (other than that it’s a laptop). I’d check your media is good - try it in a different machine for example. Can you get to the ‘try Ubuntu’ option? If so, you might be able to install from there.
